# Order of elements in MultiKeyMap

Tags: java, collections, apache-commons-collection

Recently I started using Apache Commons `MultiKeyMap` for some of my projects and in there I can have multiple values for a value.

```
MultiKeyMap typePanelUnoMap = new MultiKeyMap();
```

I want to know whether we can preserve insertion order when using `MultiKeyMap`. I know that `java.util.LinkedHashMap` can preserve the insertion order.

```
Map hshmap = new LinkedHashMap()
```

Can I have the same functionality with `MultiKeyMap`?

Thanks,
Keth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the [javadocs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiKeyMap.html)

This map is implemented as a decorator of a `AbstractHashedMap` which enables extra behaviour to be added easily.

`MultiKeyMap.decorate(new LinkedMap())` creates an ordered map.

Answer (score 0):

Since [Apache Commons Collections 4](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/), method `multiKeyMap` is being used instead of method `decorate`.

So it should be:

```java
MultiKeyMap<String, Object> multiKeyMap= MultiKeyMap.multiKeyMap(new LinkedMap<>());
```